# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString Reference Local File

Tags: ios, uiwebview, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

I have an image that I have in my bundle resources that I need to reference as a source file (src="") in my webView `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. I can reference external images from websites, but I do not know how to write the URL of the local image.

How could this be done?

Comment: Is this objective-C? Mac? iOS? Ruby? Java?

Comment: xcode. it's an ios application.

Comment: FYI, XCode is a versatile, integrated development environment used to develop for Mac, iOS, Java, Ruby and other languages and platforms.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example to show how you could do this...

in my `viewDidLoad`, I am adding some example HTML into a UIWebView as shown below: (This could easily be a `loadRequest:` call to a remote URL)

```
NSString *html = @"<html><body><img id='theImage'></img></body></html>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

You need to set the view controller as the delegate for the UIWebView, and wait until it has finished loading the HTML. You can then execute a script to amend the image URL:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // Get the path to the image in the bundle you wish to display, and create a URL from this path.
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImage.png"]];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];
    // Create a script to execute in the web view.
    NSString *script = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('theImage').src = \"%@\";", imageURL];
    // Execute the script.
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
    // Tidy up.
    [imagePath release];
}
```

Comment: Ian, thanks for the reply. I actually tried using the "stringByAppendingPathComponent" based on another tutorial I saw for a related topic. I don't know whether I executed the script incorrectly, or whether it was a faulty script, but the fact is it did not work. I will try this method once I get home, hopefully it will work. I'll get back to you.

Comment: I have tested it and it worked... but you do need to do it in the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I am running my current script in webViewDidFinishLoad, so I don't think I'll have to change the script too much. Hopefully this'll work for me! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ian, if I'm using this in a CSS "src:" should I use src: local(\"%@\"); ?

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something, but it's not working for me, even when I tested it with your example code "document.getElementById('theImage').src = \"%@\";" of course changing 'theImage' to whatever the id of the image was. I used an alert and I confirmed that the file path is indeed stored in \"%@\" but for some reason when I try to actually apply it nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't used CSS in a while, but I think you can only set a background image for an element using background-image:url('http://www.server.com/image.jpg');. Regarding the project not working, can you let me know the URL you are loading, and the ID of the image you wish to change and I'll have a look into it.

Comment: Ian, when I replace the \"%@\" with the same image file on my server it works. I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: Did some more testing. It runs fine on a simple html file like the one you had in your reply. However, if I'm running this on a website and trying to replace stuff on the website, it doesn't work. Weird.